# What is the /g in replace in Vim

Tags: vim

I was just curious what is the /g for when doing a find and replace in Vim.

I get the reason for the % in

```
:%s/search/replace/g
```

but if the % stands for 'in every line' what is /g for?

Comment: Every occurence on the line.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/g` means "for every occurence in each matching line".

Without the `g`, `:%s/pattern/repl/` will only replace the first occurence of `pattern` on each matching line.

If you run `:help s_flags` inside Vim, you can see a description of all the possible flags.